# How to run Tonic Trouble under Windows 7?

Tags: pc, tonic-trouble

I just tried, but keep getting error screen, thanks for advice.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Yes, it's DX6 game

It's Win 7 32Bit
GeForece 9800GT with latest driver
AMD Phenom X4 965 3.4G

[image: Setup Screen]

Comment: Tried Windows 2000 or XP compatibility mode ?

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to get the game running on a copy of Windows XP hosted in [VMware Workstation 8](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/) for Windows 7:

[image: Virtual success!]

Comment: running a xp vm to start the game isn't really a feasible solution for a lot of people...