# Cannot initialize Tonic Trouble due to not enough space on hard drive?

Tags: technical-issues, tonic-trouble

I am attempting to play Tonic Trouble on my laptop in which the hard drive space is 218GB free of 283GB total.  It installs fine, yet when I hit "Play" I am told there is not enough free space on my hard drive to play?  Any suggestions?

As I mentioned below, specifically, the error message says:

> "Cannot initialize Tonic Trouble. You do not have enough space on your
>   Hard Drive."

Comment: Does it say free space or memory ?

Comment: Specifically, it says....."Cannot initialize Tonic Trouble. You do not have enough space on your Hard Drive". ty :)

Comment: Tonic trouble is a old game and might not be able to detect that you got that much free space. [Related question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/40148/61395)

Comment: Have you tried running the game via compatibility mode?

Comment: Thank you Jonathan......So - no Tonic Trouble for me then :(    Have a great day!

Comment: No - have not tried Compatibility mode....was just going to Install and play on Laptop....not going online.  Not sure if I'm familiar with changing compatibility modes when not using a Browser?!

Comment: @user120032 Try that out. Change the compatibility mode to Windows XP SP 2, it could potentially work and bypass the whole "hard drive not enough space" issue.

Comment: @how dare yo u-   Would love to - does that mean I have to change my OS to XP?  Sorry -  still a novice on the computer!!   lol

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try reading up on this article, [Compatibility Mode](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/316-compatibility-mode.html).

Tonic Trouble is an old game, dating back to 1999. So try running it in either Windows XP SP 2, or an even older operating system to simulate when it was released.

Comment: Perfect - ty for all your advise and assistance!  Have a great day Dan!!  :)